# how to extract the selected value from a dropdown list with Thymeleaf and Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, html.dropdownlistfor

I have populated a list with the content from my Spring Controller (provincia) and I have another object (profile2) that I need to get the selected value from (provincia) ... and other values in my form country, etc...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editprofileabout4", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView editProfileAbout4(ModelAndView modelAndView) {

    Usuario usuario = getUsuario();
    Profile profile = profileService.getUserProfile(usuario);
    Profile2 profile2 = profile2Service.getUserProfile2(usuario);
    List<Provincia> provincia = provinciaService.readAllProvincia();

    Profile webProfile = new Profile();
    webProfile.safeCopyFrom(profile);

    modelAndView.getModel().put("edituserprofile2th", usuario);
    modelAndView.getModel().put("editprofile2about2th", profile2);
    modelAndView.getModel().put("editprovincia2th", provincia);
    modelAndView.setViewName("editprofileabout4");

    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/doeditprofileabout4", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView editProfileAbout4(ModelAndView modelAndView, @Valid Profile2 profile2, @Valid Provincia provincia,  BindingResult result) {

    modelAndView.setViewName("editprofileabout4");

    System.out.println("       !!!!!!!!!!!!! PROFILE2a: " + profile2.getBirthdate());
    System.out.println("       !!!!!!!!!!!!! PROFILE2b: " + profile2.getGender());
    System.out.println("       !!!!!!!!!!!!! PROFILE2d: " + profile2.getProvincia());
    System.out.println("       !!!!!!!!!!!!! PROFILE2x: " + provincia.toString());

    Usuario usuario = getUsuario();
    Profile2 profile = profile2Service.getUserProfile2(usuario);
    profile.setCountry(profile2.getCountry());
    profile.setGender(profile2.getGender());
    profile.setBirthdate(profile2.getBirthdate());
    profile.setProvincia(provincia);

    if (!result.hasErrors()) {
        profile2Service.save(profile);
        modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/editprofileabout4");
    }
    return modelAndView;

}
```

In my HTML, I have:

```
<form class="sky-form" id="sky-form4" action="#" th:object="${editprofile2about2th}" th:action="@{/doeditprofileabout4}" method="post">

    <section>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
            <select class="form-control" th:object="${editprovincia2th}" id="ddl" name="ddl">
            <option value="" th:text="#{editprofile.about4.provincia}">Seleccionar Provincia</option>
            <option th:each="dropDownItem : ${editprovincia2th}"
                                                    th:value="${dropDownItem.id_provincia}"
                                                    th:text="${dropDownItem.provincia}"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </section>
```

but I can not find any working example on how to extract the selected key and value (th:select) corresponding with the value in the list and get it back into the controller (or move it into de profile2 object that has a provincia wired object). I get null values for provincia in my controller after the Post.

And when I include a ( select th:field ="*{provincia}") in the HTML it gives me an error saying... There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringSelectFieldAttrProcessor' (editprofileabout4:120)
Invalid property 'provincia' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'provincia' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Thanks for your help-
Any documentation is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `th:object` attribute from `select` element and only keep one for the form, because as Thymeleaf documentation states:

> Once inside the  tag, no other th:object attribute can be
>   specified. This is consistent with the fact that HTML forms cannot be
>   nested.

`th:object` attribute on the form then needs to reference a form-backing bean, i.e. object that can hold whatever values you send through the form, e.g. *provincia*

At the moment you're trying to access property *provincia* of the List object, which simply doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks Fuudge. When I remove the th:object it doesn't work either.

Comment: it works with <select class="form-control" th:field="*{provincia}">